# Is this a case where window function should be used?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has user ids, teams, zips, and a metric:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
|  id  | team |  zip   | metric |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 0001 | t1   | 000000 |    0.0 |
| 0001 | t2   | 000001 |    1.0 |
| 0002 | t1   | 000000 |    0.0 |
| 0002 | t1   | 000001 |    1.0 |
| 0003 | t2   | 000000 |    0.0 |
| 0003 | t2   | 000001 |    0.0 |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

I need only the rows that have the highest metric for each zip, team, and id. If two zips have the same metric, pick one at random:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
|  id  | team |  zip   | metric |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 0001 | t1   | 000000 |    0.0 |
| 0001 | t2   | 000001 |    1.0 |
| 0002 | t1   | 000001 |    1.0 |
| 0003 | t2   | 000000 |    0.0 |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry don't have one. the table was provided to me as is.

Comment: Yes, this is a good use-case for window  functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by zip, team, id order by metric desc) rn 
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: for some reason the inner query returns a row number of 1 for every row

Comment: @hitodo9051: this gives one row pr `(zip, team, id)` tuple. Looking at your data, I suspect that you don't want `zip`in the `partition by` clause (although that's not what your question says), so: `row_number() over(partition by team, id order by metric desc)`

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer the question

> *is this a case where window function should be used?*

Yes it can, if you are on MySQL 8. But the old way is valid too.

Alternatively to @GMB answer, which provided the `MySQL => version 8`  window function way, you can still use a classical GROUP BY  :

```
SELECT T.*
FROM the_table T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id, metric
    FROM the_table
    GROUP by metric
) G ON T.id=G.id
```

You should ideally have an index on metric for this one.

Which one will be the most performant depends mostly on your volumes, just try both and see